# Ignite UI Grid Colorizing

Tags: javascript, json, grid, ignite-ui

I am creating an Ignite UI Grid chart bound with JSON.  One of my columns pertains to decimal numbers.  The numbers must be colored blue if they are below 20.  How would I write a JavaScript function to check if the decimal number is less than 20 and color it blue?

The code below is for one of the columns.  Each value is located in a separate json file.

```
    function createCboxSelectorsGrid() {
        $("#grid").igGrid({
            width: "100%",
            autoGenerateColumns: false,
            dataSource: data,
            responseDataKey: "results",
            dataSourceType: "json",
            columns: [
                { headerText: "2013", key: "2013", dataType: "number", width: "60px" }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.ui-iggrid .ui-iggrid-tablebody td').each(function() {
        if($(this).text() > 20) {
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
        }
        else if($(this).text() < 20) {
            $(this).css('color', 'blue');
        }
});
```